# String index out of bound exception in if statement

Tags: java, arraylist, substring, indexoutofboundsexception

```
if(line.get(count).substring(line.get(count).indexOf(p1)).equals(p1.substring(0, p1.indexOf(" ")))) {
    count++;
    if(line.get(count).contains(p1.substring(p1.indexOf(" ") + 1, p1.length())))
        System.out.println((count-1) + "     " + (line.get(count-1).indexOf(p1)) + "     " + p1);
}
```

Line is the array list with size of 65008, I'm trying to test of a name appear on two line of the file, with the first name appears on one line and the last name appears on the second line.however, the index out of bound exception occurs at the first if statement. I'm unable to realize if I did something wrong here to cause this problem as I was trying to compare the substrings.Can anyone suggest a way to solve this issue? These if statements is quite long, but I will try to tweak them later.

Comment: Are you sure that `line.get(count)` contains `p1` and that `p1` contains `" "`?

Comment: Provide your stacktrace.

Comment: Side note: don't tweak your complex code **after** you spent hours debugging it. Make sure it is **easy** to read and understand right from the beginning. Because then ... you might not need hours of debugging and turning to SO to get help doing that.
Besides: please step back for a second; and reread your question. Do you really think you are showing respect to this community by saying: "I know, my code is hard to read; and I will fix that later; in the meantime, dear internet, please help me finding the bug in that ugly piece of spaghetti code here"

Comment: yes, this is actually my last test i did similar tests before using similar line.get(count) and such, p1 was initialize to be a name with space between first and last name.

Answer (score 0):

Try using this code:

```
        if (line.get(count).substring(line.get(count).indexOf(p1))
            .equals(p1.substring(0, p1.indexOf(" ")))) {
        if (line.get(count).contains(
                p1.substring(p1.indexOf(" ") + 1, p1.length()))) {
            System.out.println((count - 1) + "     "
                    + (line.get(count - 1).indexOf(p1)) + "     " + p1);
        }
        count++;
    }
```

The main difference is that it increments count after both if conditions have run also added braces to the second if for readability. I'm not sure this will solve the problem, if not then you may need to provide more information.